# How I can do POST request in Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, captcha, 2captcha

I'm trying to mimic this web requests mechanism. I have all the data. What I need to know is how I can do the POST requests using Python Selenium?

[image: Chrome Dev]

Comment: You don't submit POST requests.  You fill in the fields as the user would have, then you simulate clicking the "submit" button.  The browser will submit the request.  You are basically a robot driving Chrome.

Comment: I can't find any button. That's why I need the post requests.

Comment: How did you generate the display above?  It could be they have another control with an `onClick` event that submits the request.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I you really just need to make a post request from python there is actually no need to use selenium at all. As Tim already pointed out you want to simulate the user interaction with the web page in selenium.

If you really just want to make a post request, you can just use [http.client](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/http.client.html):

```py
>>> import http.client, urllib.parse
>>> params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'@number': 12524, '@type': 'issue', '@action': 'show'})
>>> headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
...            "Accept": "text/plain"}
>>> conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("bugs.python.org")
>>> conn.request("POST", "", params, headers)
>>> response = conn.getresponse()
>>> print(response.status, response.reason)
302 Found
>>> data = response.read()
>>> data
b'Redirecting to <a href="http://bugs.python.org/issue12524">http://bugs.python.org/issue12524</a>'
>>> conn.close()
```